# Using rmi in a JavaEE project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, rmi, policy

I'm trying to use rmi in a java project whit NetBeans; until i was using a simple java project it was working, now instead i receive always this exception:

```
ClientRMI exception:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

I think my policy file is ok, it points to the .class files of the project and i call it using the VM option of NetBeans:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Djava.security.policy=policy
```

the working directory is the same of the policy file.

what's the problem?

Comment: Obviously your .policy file is *not* OK. Either it doesn't grant that permission to the required codebase or it isn't being loaded at all.

Comment: this is my policy file:                                         grant codebase "/home/nicola/NetBeansProjects/SVN/trunk/Comunicazione6/build/jar/comunicazione6" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: So clearly it isn't being loaded. Can you run your client with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure`? The output at the point of failure will show you clearly what policy permissions are in force.

Comment: thank you @EJP , using it I solved the problem.. even if now I use this policy file: grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission "" , "";
};